# How to find the minimum price of the product from a list of subproducts

Tags: java, algorithm

I am making a program where it takes a txt file as input, and find the best price of the list of products

for example,

```
teddy bear
painted glass eyeball,10.5,2,glass;paint 
glass,5,0,
paint,4,0,
teddy bear,null,4,painted glass eyeball;tiny shirt;faux bear fur fabric;sewing thread
faux bear fur fabric,15,2,bear;yarn
bear,100,0,
yarn,2,0,
sewing thread,13,0,
tiny shirt,24,0,
```

in the following example, our target_product is teddy bear, and on line 5, it has a null (meaning, you won't be able to just buy the whole teddy bear), and the 4 is input_product_size which stands for the amount of products required to make the target_product, and the rest are the input_products

painted glass eyeball, in line 2, can be bought for $10.5 or can be made with 2 ingredients, glass, paint

glass can be bought for $5, and requires no other ingredients to make.
Paint can be bought for $4, and requires no other ingredients.
but since making the painted glass eyeball costs $9, and buying costs $10.5, we will make it instead of buying it.

tiny shirt can be bought for $24
faux bear fur fabric can be bought for $15, or can be made with 2 ingredients, bear, and yarn
bear can be bought for $100
yarn can be bought for $2
but since the total of bear and yarn is $102 which is larger than $15, we will just buy the fabric instead of making it.
sewing thread can be bought for $13

so the total output for teddy bear's minimum price should be

```
9+24+15+13=61
```

Another example would be making a sandwich

```
sandwich
mayonnaise,1,0,
sand,0,0,
bread,3,3,yeast;water;flour
flour,1,0,
water,1,0,
yeast,1,0,
sandwich,10,6,mayonnaise;sand;bread;mozzarella;bacon;salt
bacon,3,1,pig
pig,1000,0,
salt,1,2,sea salt;iodine
iodine,40,0,
sea salt,.5,0,
mozzarella,3,0,
```

we found that sandwich can be bought for $10, or can be made with 6 ingredients from this line

```
sandwich,10,6,mayonnaise;sand;bread;mozzarella;bacon;salt
```

mayo costs $1

sand costs $0

bread costs $3 or requires 3 ingredients to make: flour, water, and yeast

flour costs $1
water costs $1
and yeast costs $1

so both making the product and buying it won't make a difference
mozzarella costs $3

bacon costs $3, or requires 1 ingredient to make: pig
since pig costs $1000, we can just buy bacon for $3

salt costs $1 or requires 2 ingredients to make, sea salt and iodine
since the total of sea salt and iodine is $40.5, more than $1, we can buy sea salt.

the total of making this sandwich would cost

```
Mayo $1
Sand $0
Bread $3
Bacon $3
Mozarella $3
Salt $1 

-------------
Total: $11
```

but since buying this sandwich only costs $10, we will have $10 as our output.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class BestPrice {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("teddybear.txt"));

        // BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line, input_products = null;

        // setting first line as our target product
        String target_product = in.readLine();

        int finalprice = 0, totalPrice = 0, input_product_size = 0;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] words = line.split(",");
            for (String word : words) {
                if (word.equals(target_product)) {
                    if (words[1].equals("null")) {
                        // find the line where the target_product is,
                        // and parse it to get the rest of the information
                        String product_name = words[0];
                        String price_to_purchase = words[1];
                        input_product_size = Integer.parseInt(words[2]);
                        input_products = words[3];
                        if (input_product_size != 0) {
                            String[] ingredients = words[3].split(";");
                            for (int i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++) {
                                if(word.equals(ingredients[i])) {}
                            }
                        }
                        // System.out.println(product_name + ", " + price_to_purchase + ", " +
                        // input_products);
                    } else {
                        // keep track of the cost of buying target_product
                        finalprice += Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (input_product_size > 1) {

            }
        }
        System.out.println(finalprice);

    }

}
```

im thinking about a 2D array or even a hashmap of lists but im sure the best way to approach this here. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi perhaps use dynamic programming?

Comment: @jspcal but what data structure would i use, im a little confused here.

Comment: love that bacon has one ingredient.... pig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class to represent each product, like so:

```
public class Product {
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private Product[] ingredients;
    ...
    public Product(String name, double price, Product... ingredients) {
        // populate instance variables
    }
}
```

I can't tell what your input is supposed to be, so obviously you might have more fields in the class. It looks like it's in CSV format but it's severely malformed. You can add getters and setters as needed.

After you've created that class you can simply make a `List<Product>` and populate it with the values from your input.

**long edit:**
Using your sandwich example, we have the input `sandwich,10,6,mayonnaise;sand;bread;mozzarella;bacon;salt`. Splitting it on the commas gives us this array:

`["sandwich","10","6","mayonnaise;sand;bread;mozzarella;bacon;salt"]`.

Let's just assume this array is called `words` like it is in your code. `Product#name` for a given instance would be `words[0]`, `Product#price` would be `words[1]`, and so on. You'll also have to split `words[3]`, or your list of ingredients, on the semicolons and pass those in.

You'll also have to find a way to construct Product objects from those names, because right now, you don't know what the prices of those ingredients are. One decent way to do this would be to create a "cache" of known `Products` and search through it by name. The other way would be to provide the prices of the ingredients in the input.

Hopefully this clears things up some. I know it's a long read.

Comment: The input is supposed to be a txt file with the products presented and formatted like above. What would you do if a product has subproducts (for example, the faux fur fabric, or the salt in either examples)

Comment: I just saw that. Added an edit. 

If you don't know how varargs work (like the `Product... ingredients` argument in the constructor), you can read up on them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html). They're a nice language feature that you should definitely learn about if you haven't already.

Comment: Thank you, can you give me some pointers on how to parse all the data into a class like that from the txt file?

Comment: this is a classic recursive binary tree problem. Everything is an ingredient, and every ingredient can contain ingredients

Comment: Looks like you have most of it down. Just pick out the different parts from the `words` array and put them into the `Product` constructor appropriately. Like I said, my example isn't exactly what you need, so add arguments/getters/setters as needed.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf can you give me an example of how this works?

Comment: The `ingredients` field in my example demonstrates exactly what Thomas Andolf is talking about. Each product may have ingredients, or "sub-products", that it's made of. Calculating the price to buy a product as opposed to making it yourself is a matter of iterating through the ingredients and adding their prices together.

Comment: im still stuck on how to implement the binary tree with the idea of creating the class with varargs of products and ingredients

Comment: one more question, how do you deal with the null in the first teddy bear example?

Comment: To make it compatible with the `double` primitive type, you could make it `-1` instead of `null` and handle a special case for `-1` wherever appropriate.

Comment: What about converting the string of products in words[3] into a Product[]?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195087/discussion-between-trvlr-and-mco).